# reference a passed string parameter to partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, controller, partial-views

I want to pass a string variable to a partial view but im not sure how to display the string parameter to the partial view. I tried some answers i found on similar questions but i got the following output:

"my_app.Models.DogTreatments" . Can anyone tell me why is that?

Here is my code:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CasIndex(int Sid)
    {

        string treat = dbContext.DogTreatments.Where(x => x.Sid == Sid).SingleOrDefault().ToString();




        //  ViewBag.TList = dbContext.DogTreatments.Where(x => x.Sid == Sid);

        return PartialView("DisplayTreatments", treat);
    }
```

View page:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/DisplayTreatments.cshtml")
```

Partial view:

```
@model string

@{
    Layout = null;
}

@Model
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is correct because of your LINQ statement.

```
string treat = dbContext.DogTreatments.Where(x => x.Sid == Sid).SingleOrDefault().ToString();
```

This `dbContext.DogTreatments.Where(x => x.Sid == Sid)` filters all the DogTreatments `Where` x.Sid == Sid

This `.SingleOrDefault()` selects a `single object` of type `DogTreatments` or default(null).

The `toString()` will convert the object type to its string format hence `my_app.Models.DogTreatments`

Perhaps this would satisfies your requirement:

Return the object from  LINQ query:

```
var treat = dbContext.DogTreatments.Where(x => x.Sid == Sid).SingleOrDefault();
return PartialView("DisplayTreatments", treat);
```

The Partial View will look like:

```
@using my_app.Models.DogTreatments //(this might need to be fixed)
@model DogTreatments

@{
    Layout = null;
}

// in here you can access the DogTreatments object
// These are just examples as I don't know from question what DogTreatments properties are
   @if(Model != null) 
   {
    @Model.Name 
    @Model.Treatment
   }
```

Comment: If my answer has helped, please consider accepting it. Thanks